# 100% width navbar without horizontal scroll-bar, in html-css

Tags: html, css

I have a hero image, and on the top of it, I want a logo and menu, 
I have given below properties to hero image. and for nav bar I have given a       `position: absolute; and width : 100%`.

I dont want that horizontant scroll bar, please help.[this is how my page look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlDAH.jpg)

```
height: 551px; width: 100%;background: url(../_images/banner_1.JPG) no-repeat;background-size: cover;position: relative;
```

Comment: Already you have your logo and menu. What is your plan for menu, you want it to be vertical , can you create a jsfiddle.

Comment: I don't know JSfiddle, I have added a logo and menu in "navbar" div, I want that navbar div should have a 100% width, but at the same time it should not create a horizontal scroll-bar.
because when i am applying 100% width to navbar , its creating horizontal scroll bar.

Answer (score 1):

You mean window horizontal scroll-bar, so to hide that add below code and change you navbar div to 100%,

```
body{
overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your quick answer, I added a overflow-x: hidden, in a body. And it helped me to remove horizontal scroll bar.
but still my navbar is going outside the window, I can't see my last menu item.

Comment: @DhawalShingare Welcome, I could see padding between your links reduce that.

Answer (score 0):

for removing horiontal scroll bar

add overflow-x: hidden

Comment: I added a overflow-x: hidden, in a body. And it helped me to remove horizontal scroll bar. but still my navbar is going outside the window, I can't see my last menu item